# How to Filter Elequent query By Subquery Result?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to Filter my Query by the Result of the Subquery in the initial Query
when i run the code above i get an error says that column printed not found

```
            $data = Order::
                  join('clients', 'orders.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
                ->join('addresses', 'orders.address_id', '=', 'addresses.id')
                ->join('br_codes', 'br_codes.id', '=', 'orders.br_code_id')
                ->join('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->join('cities', 'addresses.city_id', '=', 'cities.id')
                ->select([
                    'orders.id',
                    'orders.id as OrderID',
                    'clients.name as clientname',
                    'br_codes.br_code',
                    'addresses.address',
                    'cities.name as cityname',
                    'addresses.phone',
                    'addresses.zip_code',
                    'users.name as username',
                    'orders.created_at',
                    'orders.status',
                    'cities.tap',
                    'orders.paid',
                    'orders.recover',
                    'orders.date_postponed as reported',
                    'orders.status_shipper as shipper',
                    DB::raw('(select count(*) from notes where notes.order_id = orders.id) cnotes'),
                    DB::raw('(select count(*) from addresses ad2 JOIN clients cl on cl.id=ad2.client_id where addresses.phone = ad2.phone AND cl.user_id='.Auth::id().') dupuser'),
                    DB::raw('(select sum(items.quantity*items.price) from items where items.order_id = orders.id) price'),
                    DB::raw('(select count(*) from notes where notes.order_id = orders.id and notes.note like "%Invoice printed%" and notes.user_id='.Auth::id().') printed'),
                    'orders.pin',
                    DB::raw('(select users.name from users join affect_orders  on affect_orders.user_id=users.id  where affect_orders.order_id=orders.id  limit 1) as shipper')
                ])->whereIn('orders.status',[1,4]);

   if($request->printed){
      $data->where('printed','>',1);
    }else{
       $data->where('printed',0);
    }
```

Comment: The only way to do this is to wrap this whole query in another query that has that condition the same way you'd do this when writing a normal SQL query. Also there's no point in using eloquent if you want to use joins instead of relationships.

Answer (score -1):

after some deep digging i found the solution which is :

```
               if ($request->print_status==1) {
                    $data->having('printed','>',0);
               }//none printed
               elseif ($request->print_status==2) {
                        $data->having('printed',0);
               }
```